# Activity sometimes doesn't find a Service by using ActivityManager

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm developing a very simple android app for audio streaming. From the Activity I start and stop a Service that has to manage a MediaPlayer and every time I open the main activity I check if the service is already running.
It works fine but I had a problem that I can't figure out.

It happened for once that opening the app when the service was still running, my service wasn't found and I couldn't stop it by using the stop button I've implemented.

Here it is some code:

To check if the service is running:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (StreamingRadio.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then when Activity onStart() is called:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(isMyServiceRunning()) {
        streamingIsLive=true;
        ...
        if(!isRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("startprogress"));
            isRegistered=true;
        }
    }

}
```

and onStop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(isRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(onNotice);
        isRegistered=false;
    }

}
```

While as far as concern my Play and Stop button:

```
public void onButtonPlay(View v) {

    if(!streamingIsLive) {
        streamingIsLive=true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StreamingRadio.class);
        startService(intent);
            ....
    }
}

public void onButtonStop(View v) {

    if(streamingIsLive) {
        streamingIsLive=false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StreamingRadio.class);
        stopService(intent);
            ...
    }
}
```

What could this problem be?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be relaying on `getRunningServices()` as its not intended for use in production as noted in [API docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29):

> Return a list of the services that are currently running.
>
> **Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.**

Rather, you have to keep reference whether the service is running within its `onCreate()`, `onDestroy()`, `onStartCommand()`, `onLowMemory()`, etc.

Comment: What if I instantiate a final static myservice object into the service and I do something like:

        public onCreate() {
           myserviceobject=this;
           ...
        }

and

        public onDestroy(){
           myserviceobject=null;
           ...
        }

I'm not figuring out what is the best compromise between reliability/performances.